# Crystal Reports XI - comparison report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have the following scenario.

Customer A with multiple address IDs - 01, 02, 03, etc.

My user wants me to take specific data fields in address ID 01 and compare to the same fields in the other addresses for the customer.  When field values are found to be different, print all data fields for Address ID 01 (as line 1) and print a line for each other address that is different but only print the data field that is different (or print all fields and highlight the one that is different).

I'm having a difficult time determining how to approach this one.

### Greatly appreciate any help anyone can provide.

I think I need to provide a better explanation of what I need to do:

I have multiple address IDs such as 01, 02, 03, etc. Address ID 01 is the main address record.  I need to compare the data elements of each of the other Address IDs (ex. 02, 03, 04 etc) to Address ID 01.  If any differences are found, I need to print one line that includes all the data elements for Address 01, and one line for each other Address ID that is different and only print the fields that are different from Address 01. 
Any idea how I should approach this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of the `Suppress` formula to do this.  General outline:

Place the Address on the Detail line

Use a formula ([here's a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599476/formula-for-suppressing-field-if-duplicate-in-crystal-reports)) to suppress each field if it is the same as that field on the the previous line for the same customer

Set the Detail row to be suppressed if blank ("Suppress Blank Section" in the Section Expert)

Comment: Hi AHiggins - Thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately that's not what I need to do but it's close.  My requirement is as follows: I have multiple address IDs such as 01, 02, 03.  I need to compare the data elements of 02 to those in 01, 03 to 01, etc.  Each of the addresses are compared to 01.  Any idea how I should approach this?  Many thanks!